# Show notification for Android O and above without AppCompat

Tags: android, android-notifications

So I have ultralight app without any libs, except Crashlytics.

I want to show notifications on all versions of Android, but there is no constructor or method to set channel id for Android O+.

My code looks like this for now

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    //Some builder things

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("service_id",
                context.getString(R.string.app_name),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(id, notification);
```

Is there any compat lite lib only for notifications?

Comment: Make sure you have updated dependency of appcompat.

Comment: @SurenderKumar lol what?? Did you read my question?

Comment: The constructor option only come when u have updated dependency. When u update the dependency your old constructor will be get deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `Notification.Builder` and `NotificationCompact.Builder` can do this:

```
Notification.Builder(context, "channelId")
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channelId")
```

and they have `setChannelId` method.

Comment: or you can use the NotificationManager to set Channel id right? Dewey Reed

Comment: @ABr I don't think it's possible. Every notification has a channel id so the system knows which channel the notification should be.

Comment: @DeweyReed thnx for you answer, I forgot about not compat builders.